# insert values in 3 table if the values do not exist or update it if ixist

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

i have 3 table governorate district village and i want to be able to insert in each one of them values ... but i need to check first if the user input is not empty for the governorate field to be able to insert the district and to check if the user input for the district field is not empty to allow user to enter the village value with its coordinations ..

so i write this code but it do not work as i want can anyone help me ???to see where i did the mistake .

until now i just write the code for the village to add and for the governorate to remove

**even if the values are inserted the system display the error msg :you must fill one of these fields befor you submit!!**

## code

```
 if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
       if(isset($_POST['city']) || isset( $_POST['lat']) || isset($_POST['long']) == "" )
       {
         $errorMSG = "you must fill one of these fields befor you submit!!";
       }
      /* 
       if($_POST['gov'])
       {
           $gov = $_POST['gov'];
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO governorate (governorate_id, governorate_name)VALUES('', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());
           echo $gov;
       }
       //******for adding district*********************
       elseif($_POST['dist'])
       {
           $dist = $_POST['dist'];
           $gov = $_POST['gov']; 
           if($gov)
           {
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());

           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO governorate (governorate_id, governorate_name)VALUES('', '$gov')") or die(mysql_error());

           echo $dist;
           }
           else{ $errorMSG = "You can not add District Without relate a Governorate for this district";}
       }
       */
       //********************for adding city****************************//

     if($_POST['city'])
       {
          $city = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['city']);
       $lat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lat']);
       $long = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['long']);
       $dist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dist']); 
       $gov = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['gov']);
           if(!$dist)
           {
               $errorMSG = "you can not add city without having relation with district";
           }
           elseif($lat =="" || $long ==""){ $errorMSG = "You can not add village Without its coordinations";}
           else
           {
               $sqld = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')") or die(mysql_error());
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO village (id, village_name, district_id, lattitude, longitude)VALUES('', '$city', '$dist' ,'$lat',  '$long')")or die(mysql_error());

           }
       }

   }
/////******************for remove****************************************************//
/////********************************************************************************//
   if(isset($_POST['remove']))
   {
       if($_POST['gov'])
       {
           $gov = $_POST['gov'];
           $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM governorate WHERE governorate_name = '$gov'")or die(mysql_error());
       }
   }
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Your database could be easily hacked, and all information deleted. All you'd need to do is in your delete functionality, in the `gov` post variable, type in `' OR 1=1--`. I highly suggestion you quickly, as in now, escape ALL your post data.

Comment: Why `isset($_POST['long']) == ""`?

Comment: @PiLHA  in this statement i mean that if the user do not enter any value i the lat filed and leave it empty  is this wrong ??

Comment: @user2396708 I do not know if it is possible to make these two checks at the same time, just in case try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

As far as your error message concerned *'...even if the values are inserted the system display the error msg: **you must fill one of these fields befor you submit!!**...'*

Your conditional is wrong. Change

```
if(isset($_POST['city']) || isset( $_POST['lat']) || isset($_POST['long']) == "" )
```

to

```
if ((!isset($_POST['city']) || $_POST['city'] == "") 
 && (!isset($_POST['lat'])  || $_POST['lat'] == "" )
 && (!isset($_POST['long']) || $_POST['long'] == "")) {
```

On a side note: your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Switch to mysqli or PDO and learn prepared statements.